# how can optimize query with large json data

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    info = models.JosnField(default=dict())  # contain very large data

....
....
....
....

queryset = MyModel.objects.all().order_by('id')[:200000] # it's very slow
```

now i'm trying on compress json data

Comment: you want the whole model fields data?